# FB users for QA use

Tags: facebook, testing, automated-tests

Our application use FB user to do different actions (such as like and comment)
Is there a way to generate multiple users in FB that will have a vaild token for the actions, without opening multiple fake FB account for our tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Test User endpoint provided by facebook. See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

With that you should be able to achieve what you want.